# "To open a discussion"?

Tags: word-usage, formality, formal-language

There are several ways to paraphrase this sentence and I would want to know which is the best one, or rather to know which is more appropriate when talking or writing an essay / project.

- > To open / begin a discussion
- > To open / begin an argument

In addition, to know if there's a more formal way to say this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you asking about whether you use open vs begin with each word, or whether it's better in the context of an essay to refer to a particular discourse as a discussion vs an argument?

Comment: @childofsoong the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me list the frequency of each expression in [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/):

- open a discussion: 9
- start a discussion: 12
- begin a discussion: 19
- open an argument: 0
- start an argument: 24
- begin an argument: 1

It's seems reasonable to me that *to open an argument* should not be an idiomatic collocation, unlike *to start/begin an argument*, because an argument doesn't exist until you start it, and therefore there's nothing to *open* (before it's started).
On the other hand, a discussion about a particular subject exists potentially (in the sense that there already exist some untold facts about the subject of the discussion), and therefore you can *open* it.

I don't have a definite idea as to why you cannot *begin an argument*, whereas *starting an argument* would be fine (take a look at [this n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=begin+an+argument%2C+start+an+argument&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbegin%20an%20argument%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstart%20an%20argument%3B%2Cc0) too). Surprisingly, *start a fight*, *start a feud*, etc are all acceptable collocations, but if you substitute *begin* for *start*, they turn out to be uncommon. This merits a whole other question, but maybe [this synonym discussion](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/start) from Merriam-Webster Dictionary could provide a clue, (where it says that *start* applies especially to first steps):

> ***Begin***, ***start*** , and ***commence*** are often interchangeable.
>   ***Begin***, opposed to *end*, is the most general: *begin a trip*, *began dancing*.
>   ***Start***, opposed to stop, applies especially to **first** actions, steps, or stages:  *the work started slowly*.
>   ***Commence*** can be more formal or bookish than begin or start: *commence firing*, *commenced a conversation*.

And to answer your final question about their formality, you can see from the discussion above that by replacing *start/begin* with *commence* you could have a  more formal or bookish expression. But I personally don't see why you should do that, as there's nothing especially informal about the original expressions.
However, here'e [*Cambridge Dictionary*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/begin-or-start) stating that *begin is more formal than start* (only when they can be used interchangeably, of course).